# How to access control inside a TitleTemplate of RadPane

Tags: silverlight, button, telerik, datatemplate, gridsplitter

How can I get a handle for the GridSplitter inside the TitleTemplate of RadPane

```
<telerik:RadPane TitleTemplate="{StaticResource radPaneHeaderFormat}" ContextMenuTemplate="{x:Null}" CanDockInDocumentHost="False"  x:Name="radPane" Header="HeaderTitle" CanUserClose="False" CanFloat="False"    VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="radPaneHeaderFormat}"  ">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="670" MaxWidth="678"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="ViewButton" Margin="0,0,5,0" Style="{StaticResource LeftArrowButtonStyle}" Click="ViewButton_Click" />
            <TextBlock Text="Summary" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
            <sdk:GridSplitter Height="Auto"  Grid.Column="2" Name="HeaderSplitter" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource newGridSplitterStyle}" />                               
             <TextBlock Text="Note"  Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Can any one help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where you want to access the `GridSplitter`, but, given that you have a `Button` with a `Click` event handler, I'll show you how you can access it in there:

```
    private void ViewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var panel = button.Parent as Panel;
        if (panel != null)
        {
            GridSplitter splitter = panel.Children.OfType<GridSplitter>().First();
            // do stuff with the GridSplitter...
        }
    }
```

You will need to add a line `using System.Linq;` if you don't already have one.

In this case I'm making use of the fact that the button's `Click` event handler passes us the button that was clicked, and that the `Button` and the `GridSplitter` have the same parent.